# Julia load dataframe from s3 csv file

Tags: amazon-s3, julia, julia-dataframe

I'm having trouble finding an example to follow online for this simple use-case:

Load a CSV file from an s3 object location to julia DataFrame.

Here is what I tried that didn't work:

```
using AWSS3, DataFrames, CSV

filepath = S3Path("s3://muh-bucket/path/data.csv")

CSV.File(filepath) |> DataFrames            # fails

# but I am able to stat the file
stat(filepath)

#=
Status(  mode = -rw-rw-rw-,
  ...etc  
  size = 2141032 (2.0M),
  blksize = 4096 (4.0K),
  blocks = 523,
  mtime = 2021-09-01T23:55:26,
  ...etc
=#
```

I can also read the file to a string object locally:

```
data_as_string = String(AWSS3.read(filepath);
#"column_1\tcolumn_2\tcolumn_3\t...etc..."
```

My AWS config is in order, I can access the object from julia locally.

How to I get this into a dataframe?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to help from the nice people on julia slack channel (#data).

```
bytes = AWSS3.read(S3Path("s3://muh-bucket/path/data.csv"))

typeof(bytes)
# Vector{UInt8} (alias for Array{UInt8, 1})

df = CSV.read(bytes, DataFrame)
```

Bingo, I'm in business. The CSV.jl maintainer mentions that S3Path types used to work when passed to CSV.read, so perhaps this will be even simpler in the future.

[Helpful SO post for getting AWS configs in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67806026/how-to-use-the-package-awss3-jl-to-connect-to-an-s3-bucket-running-on-an-ec2-ins)